# ViewModelScope and IdlingResource

Tags: scope, android-espresso, android-viewmodel

in my project im using AndroidX Lifecycle ViewModel (2.2.0-rc01) and im in the need to write a couple of espresso test, to tell espresso that the Application tested is still busy. 
The viewModelScope need to tell that espresso is busy.

```
val ViewModel.viewModelScope: CoroutineScope
    get() {
        val scope: CoroutineScope? = this.getTag(JOB_KEY)
        if (scope != null) {
            return scope
        }
        return setTagIfAbsent(JOB_KEY,
            CloseableCoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate))
    }

internal class CloseableCoroutineScope(context: CoroutineContext) : Closeable, CoroutineScope 
{
     override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = context

     override fun close() {
         coroutineContext.cancel()
     }
}
```

Is extending viewModelScope and using the CountingIdleResource a valid solution ?
Or do i just need the InstantTaskExecutorRule ?

The Coroutines Job has #invokeOnCompletion function which i could use to count down the idling resource.

thanks

It looks like there is some ongoing discussion: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/242

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution?